# Compilation Error in the model- JQGRID ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I want to implement CRUD operations using JQGrid. I am following tutorial from here.

[JqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx).

I have added a new MVC3  Project using VS 2010. I have added the model called **OrdersJqGridModel** to the model folder in the project. I have not changed the default folder layouts.

This is the code it looks in the model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Trirand.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace JQGridMVCExamples.Models
{
    public class OrdersJqGridModel
    {
        public JQGrid OrdersGrid { get; set; }

        public OrdersJqGridModel()
        {            
            OrdersGrid = new JQGrid
                             {
                                 Columns = new List() //using the generic type System.Collections.Generic.List<T> requires 1 type arguments- **ERROR HERE**
                                 {
                                     new JQGridColumn { DataField = "OrderID", 
                                                        // always set PrimaryKey for Add,Edit,Delete operations
                                                        // if not set, the first column will be assumed as primary key
                                                        PrimaryKey = true,
                                                        Editable = false,
                                                        Width = 50 },                                    
                                     new JQGridColumn { DataField = "CustomerID", 
                                                        Editable = true,
                                                        Width = 100 },
                                     new JQGridColumn { DataField = "OrderDate",                                                         
                                                        Editable = true,
                                                        Width = 100, 
                                                        DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" },
                                     new JQGridColumn { DataField = "Freight", 
                                                        Editable = true,
                                                        Width = 75 },
                                     new JQGridColumn { DataField = "ShipName",
                                                        Editable =  true
                                                      }                                     
                                 },
                                 Width = Unit.Pixel(640),
                                 Height = Unit.Percentage(100)
                             };

            OrdersGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowRefreshButton = true;            
        }

    }
}
```

**ERROR:**
It complains with the following error
using the generic type System.Collections.Generic.List requires 1 type arguments- 
**Can anyone point me, why this error  is happening?**

I have used builtin MVC3 web grid before, but I need to implement inline CRUD operations.

Can anyone point me any other inline crud operations tutorail using Grid in asp.net MVC

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<JQGridColumn>()`

That demo needs to be changed but they haven't done it. However, if you download the trial version or have the full licensed version, these will include an example project for VS 2010 Razor MVC3 and they use `List<JQGridColumn>()` for this very example.